# How can I make the default Nav Menu into a Responsive toggle navigation menu?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have working on a site( http://sitepreview.net63.net/ ). But I want to make it a responsive site. So I want to make the navigation menu( which comes from the Wordpress Menu Bar ) a toggle navigation menu in the small screens. I am giving an image link here, where you can check what I want, please go to this link: http://sitepreview.net63.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/responsive-nav-menu.jpg .

Comment: Would you like to use bootstrap?

Comment: I have used code from this site: http://www.rvamedia.com/wordpress/collapsible-responsive-menu-for-genesis but it wouldn't work for me. @ Danko.

Comment: I don't like to use Bootstrap as this site has already been made with a Responsive THeme. @ Bharath

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `media queries` to disable the `nav` and show the mobile `nav`. You then can use some jQuery to know if the screen size is this size to add click function to the nav.

**Something like this**

HTML

```
<nav class="fullNav">
  <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Blah Blah</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav class="mobileNav">
  <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Blah Blah</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.fullNav {
  /*Code goes here */
}
.mobileNav {
  /*Code goes here */
    display: none;
}
```

Media Query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    .fullNav {
      display: none;
    }
    .mobileNav {
      display: block;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
if ($(window).width() < 680) { // if statement is not 100% needed
  $('.mobileNav').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children().slideToggle();
  }
}
```

Header tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;">`

Comment: Actually I want to use the default Nav menu which will come from the Wordpress Dashboard : Appearance->Menu. So will it work there please?

Comment: Yes it will work if you use media queries, they are used to change what ever styles you choose when the screen size is under a certain size. If you don't hide/show each nav then you will need to change all of the styles to match the mobile look. It's 100% possible just requires more work/testing!

Comment: I have used this and also customized some but it is not working. You can check in the site.